# MySQL join three tables(one column or another based on condition)

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

1. `users`: I need the `username` column of the row whose `id` column matches the `uid` argument for the query
2. `matches`: I need the `id` of the row, and one of `liked` or `liker` columns as `uid`. Meaning, if the `uid` the query gets as argument is let's say 34 and the `liker` is `34`, I get the `liked` column, which could be `789` or whatever.
3. `pic_url`: it has several rows for one user, but I need only the row where `profile_pic = 1` (which is only gonna be one)
   So far I've written this:

```sql
SELECT
      matches.id,
      IF(matches.liker = ${uid}, matches.liked, matches.liker) AS matches.uid,
      users.username,
      pic_urls.url AS profilePic
    FROM matches
    JOIN users
      ON matches.uid = users.id
    JOIN pic_urls
      ON users.id = pic_urls.user_id
    WHERE profile_pic = 1
```

I don't know where to put the condition to filter the rows in the `pic_urls` table, so I get only the one where the `profile_pic` column is `1` (there's only one with this)
The tables in question are:

```
mysql> describe matches;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| liker | int unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| liked | int unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe users;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username  | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstname | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
...

mysql> describe pic_urls;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| profile_pic | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want:

```
-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   id  |   uid     | username  |      profpic     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
|   1   |   33      |  bob      |   someurl        |
|   5   |   22      |  frank    |   someurl        |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

Where `id` and `uid` are columns from the `matches` table, `username` from `users` table, and `profpic` from `pic_urls`.

Comment: Did you try `where profile_pic = 1` or what is an issue exactly? Can you post the whole schema with sample data and what is wanted output example?

Comment: @Muflix yes, sorry I didn't paste it in the original question. It says I have an error in line 3 (probably the `matches.uid` part).

Comment: @Muflix I don't know how to get the whole schema (sorry SQL noob here) but the output I want is:
matches.id, matches.uid, users.username, pic_urls.url

Comment: The thing is that the `matches` table doesn't have a `uid` column, it's an alias I'm creating. Could that be an issue?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the question. Try to edit the question with create schema script or ER diagram and provide little bit of context.

Comment: @Muflix what part exactly you don't understand :-)

Answer (score 1):

This was the query I was after:

```sql
    SELECT
      matches.id,
      users.id AS uid,
      users.username,
      pic_urls.url
    FROM matches
    JOIN users ON IF(matches.liker = ${uid}, matches.liked, matches.liker) = users.id
    JOIN pic_urls ON IF(matches.liker = ${uid}, matches.liked, matches.liker) = pic_urls.user_id
    WHERE profile_pic = 1
```